# jQuery UI Show Blind queuing issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button, jquery-hover

I am having trouble with a button i'm trying to apply an animation on.
The effect i'm trying to create is that a button with a white border and transparent background gets filled with white background-color on hover from left to right and clears again from left to right when the user mouse goes out. While also the font-color changes to a readable color.

To achieve this I have a div with two a in it which are position on top of each other. Why two a elements? So the user can click whichever one is on top/shown.

HTML:

```
<div class="block-button"> <a href="#" class="first">Click me</a>
<a href="#" class="second"></a>
```

CSS

```
.block-button .first {
z-index: 8;
color: #fff;
}

.block-button .second {
z-index: 7;
background-color: white;
```

}

jQuery

```
 //Buttons
$("a.second").hide();
$(".block-button").each(function () {
    $(this).hover(function (e) {
        $(this).find("a.second").show("blind", {
            direction: "left",
            easing: 'easeOutCubic'
        },500, function () {
           //Callback
        });
    }, function (e) {
        $(this).find("a.second").hide("blind", {
            direction: "right",
            easing: 'easeOutCubic'
        }, 500, function () {
            //Callback
        });
    });
});
```

I'm having trouble though handling the queuing of the blind animation though. Normally i would solve this with jQuery.stop() but it doesn't work correctly at the moment.

When i disable stop, naturally all the animations get stacked so continuously hovering/un-hovering will make the animation repeat over and over.

When i enable stop though, when you enter the element again while it is still animating (you can clearly see this when using a high duration in the animate function) the last animation doesn't get called correctly.

It's kinda hard to explain but these jFiddles make these pretty clear i think.

Stop enabled: [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/g4JPz/4/)

Stop disabled: [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/g4JPz/1/)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are making it way too hard on yourself. All you have to do is overlap two elements; a background and a foreground. By changing the size of the background, you can animate the button.

I rewrote it entirely. [Check out my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4JPz/7/).

Using `position: absolute;` and `position: relative;` I have overlapped both elements. The dynamic width is preserved, in case you want to use multiple buttons with different text.

Because I am changing `width` on-hover with the `animate()` method, `stop()` does seem to work properly.

Comment: Though not entirely the effect I was trying to achieve,  your technique animating the width instead of using jQuery-UI's show('blind') function did work. I posted my final code below.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the effect I wanted using the technique Tim suggested in his answer. Animating the width of a background span seemed to do the trick!

Javascript:

```
$('a.btn-pretty').hover(function(e) {
$(this).children('span.background').stop().animate({
    'width': $(this).width()
}, 300,function(){
    $('span.background').css({'right':'0','left':'auto'});   
});
}, function(e) {
$(this).children('span.background').stop().animate({
    'width': 0
}, 300,function(){
     $('span.background').css({'left':'0','right':'auto'}); 
});
});
```

You can see the [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/g4JPz/10/)